# XML3D: Efficient display & change of large textures

Tags: opengl-es, rendering, webgl, 360-degrees, xml3d

I'm using XML3D and sphere model to display 360 photos. 
The problem is I need to change large textures frequently.

- What is the optimal way to use XML3D or webgl for rendering 360
  photos?
- How can I optimize the texture switching? Would it be better to have
  a set of smaller textures? Is there any set of "good practices" for
  rendering of 360 images?
- What is the optimal way to achieve blurring effect between two 360
  "sky" textures?

Comment: There are a few ways to display panoramic photos, it depends on the projection--cube maps and rectilinear projections are both common.  As for texture switching--just use one texture, unless you need higher resolution than your device supports.  Blurring--do you mean a cross-fade?  That's just a simple `mix()` call in the shader.

Comment: I wasn't asking how to display a 360 photo but how to pick the optimal way if need to dispaly many of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were switching between just two or three textures there would be faster alternatives, but with that many textures your only practical option is to load them one after the other by changing the image tag:

```
<texture name="diffuseTexture">
   <img id="photo" src="images/photo1.jpg"/>
</texture>

document.querySelector("#photo").src = "images/photo2.jpg";
```

If you profile this with large textures (4096x2048) you'll see a huge amount of time being spent in the call to gl.texImage2D, where the image data is decoded, converted and sent to the GPU. Even on a desktop this can result in stuttering, the situation gets a lot worse on mobile.

Reducing the size of your textures will speed things up a lot. For example dropping them from 4096x2048 to 2048x1024 brings the time spent in gl.texImage2D down from ~53% to ~13% on my desktop.

A more low level WebGL library might give you some more options here (such as converting the images to Uint8Arrays by hand before giving them to texImage2D) but XML3D wasn't really designed with this in mind. And as long as you're working with big textures you're going to have slowdowns no matter what you do particularly on mobile.

If you can put your photos into a video instead that would work much better since the decoding and conversion is done on the GPU in that case. Of course that has its own downsides though.

Fading one texture into another can be done very simply in a shader using a uniform variable:

```
uniform float uFade;
...
vec4 color1 = texture2D(texture1, texcoords);
vec4 color2 = texture2D(texture2, texcoords);
gl_FragColor = mix(color1, color2, uFade);
```

Blurring involves several steps. First you need to render the above mix into an offscreen FrameBuffer. That becomes an input texture for a horizontal blur shader, the output of that is given to a vertical blur shader and finally the output of that is used as the texture for the sky object during the scene rendering pass. The first three steps should be rendered onto a full screen quad.

This *can* be done in XML3D using the RenderInterface and your own RenderPasses, but IMO it's a lot of trouble to go through for an effect that isn't hugely different from a simple fade.

Comment: Maybe megatexture/virtual texture technique is a way to go here, have you heard about those?

Comment: Heard about it but I haven't really looked into it. At a glance it seems like a lot of added complexity for some very specific use cases, but I'll take a closer look at it. Thanks!

Comment: The key part here is that I know upfront how much textures i need to have prepared at any particular moment.  I each location requires one panorama and there is no more than 4 (5) exits from each "scene" to other panoramas. There is also this fact that only around 30% texture is visiable at times since you've limited fov.

Comment: Ok but at some point you need to decode, convert and send that texture data to the GPU. At 4096x2048 each texture takes 33 MB of uncompressed video memory, if you preload just the 5 exit scenes that's already 165 MB that you need to process and store on the GPU. All 360 images would be around 12 GB.

I'll take another look at our image handling on Monday to see if there's another reason for the stuttering, it's strange that I can use a 4K video as a texture with no slowdown but get big problems rapidly switching a 4K img.